# jQuery require returns an object instead of a function

Tags: jquery, node.js, jestjs, jsdom

I tried using **jQuery** with **jsdom** in one of my tests but I am unable to get it to work. The require statement for jQuery `$` returns a function when I don't pass a `window` object but the moment I do, `$` is an object and not a function.

Versions of libraries that I use,

Node.JS (14.7.0), Jest (26.6.3), jsdom (16.6.0), jQuery (3.6.0).

```js
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");
const {window} = new JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>", {
  url: 'http://localhost/',
});
const $ = require("jquery")(window);

test("jsdom and jquery are setup", () => {
  expect($("p").textContent).toBe("Hello world")
});
```

```
TypeError: $ is not a function

    at Object.<anonymous> (.../src/canary.test.js:8:10)
    at Object.asyncJestTest (.../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
    at .../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper (.../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
    at .../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Tried various answers from other SO posts, but didn't help. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe something else is defining `$` in window? Try using `jQuery` intead of `$`

Comment: @Justinas thanks, but I get `TypeError: jQuery is not a function`

Comment: I assume you also changed `const jQuery = require("jquery")`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed that line of code but couldn't get it to work. However, I replaced Jest with Mocha and it works now. Looks like Jest brings in jsdom by default and requires additional setup (which I haven't figured out yet).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get this working with Jest. So, I went ahead with Mocha instead.